# White space gap in newsletter on iPad Gmail account

Tags: html, ios, ipad, newsletter, electronic-direct-mail

I read a lot of articles about this problem.

The problem is white space gap under images on newsletter email marketing.

I have this problem in Gmail and Outlook app on my iPad and my iPhone.

I check the results and the advices on Google and the solution is only for Windows:

- insert `display:block;` on each image
- insert `line-height:0;` and `font-size:0;` in each  that contain images
- insert `font-size:0;` and `border-collapse: collapse;` in each tables

I have already the problem on iPad...

How can I fix it please?
Any advices?

Thx

Comment: You may need to add the code and a screenshot of the unwanted result to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works, if not then you have a problem.

```
<style>
Table, tr td { border-collapse:collapse;}
Img {border:0;padding:0;margin:0;}
</style>
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr><td><img style="display:block;"></td></tr>
</table>
```